# How to solve tiling problem with dancing links?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, packing-and-covering

My end goal is to create an application where the user can load in a 3D mesh and then define a box. The app then try to fit as much mesh as possible into that box.

I figure that would be a pretty difficult problem, so I start small first. Let's say I have an arbitrary simple polygons with arbitrary orientation, how would I figure out how many polygons (and of course, how) I can fit within a bounded boundary (a rectangle for example)?

I dig around and the answer always point down to the [Dancing Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) algorithm that people used to solve Sudoku. But I fail to understand what is the link between that algorithm and the problem I'm trying to solve. Can someone give me a more verbose answer?

Answer (score 1):

> ***OP.*** Let's say I have an arbitrary simple polygons with arbitrary orientation, how would I figure out how many polygons (and of course, how) I can fit within a bounded boundary (a rectangle for example)?

I wonder if you are perhaps seeking to reproduce the
[Conway criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_criterion#:%7E:text=The%20Conway%20crit)?

One of the best sources on this topic is this (relatively) recent result, for they take pains to explain the Conway criteria:

> Langerman, Stefan, and Andrew Winslow. "A quasilinear-time algorithm for tiling the plane isohedrally with a polyomino." [arXiv:1507.02762](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02762) (2015).

---

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely have a look. I wonder if for each tile, we allow arbitrary rotation, how much more complex this problem would be

Comment: "Any prototile satisfying Conway's criterion admits a periodic tiling of the plane—and does so using only translation and 180-degree rotations." So: not arbitrary rotations.

Answer (score 1):

The following recent paper shows that many problems involving packing geometric objects in the plane are $\exists\mathbb{R}$-complete:

Mikkel Abrahamsen, Tillmann Miltzow and Nadja Seiferth, Framework for $\exists\mathbb{R}$-Completeness of Two-Dimensional Packing Problems,
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.07558